# Uploading a List of Assets to Firebase Storage and get a List of Strings Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage, assets

I'm having a question.

So I'm trying to upload multiple pictures into Firebase Storage, these are getting into Phone Memory through a *MultiImage* picker which only Saves the data into a List < Asset > , here the code:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:multi_image_picker2/multi_image_picker2.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../widgets/bottom_navigation_bar.dart';
import '../providers/selling.dart';

//Property Features Screens
import '../screens/land_lot_size_features.dart';
import '../screens/condo_property_details_features.dart';
import '../screens/townhose_property_detais_features.dart';
import '../screens/home_property_details_features.dart';

import '../screens/selling_bathrooms.dart';

//Next Page Pricing
import '../screens/pricing_property.dart';

class MultipleImageDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/multi-picker';

  @override
  _MultipleImageDemoState createState() => _MultipleImageDemoState();
}

class _MultipleImageDemoState extends State<MultipleImageDemo> {
  List<Asset> images = <Asset>[];
  double screenWidth = 0;
  bool isLoading = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    images = Provider.of<Selling>(context, listen: false).images;
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> loadAssets() async {
    List<Asset> resultList = <Asset>[];

    try {
      resultList = await MultiImagePicker.pickImages(
        maxImages: 12,
        enableCamera: true,
        selectedAssets: images,
        cupertinoOptions: CupertinoOptions(takePhotoIcon: "chat"),
        materialOptions: MaterialOptions(
          actionBarColor: "#abcdef",
          actionBarTitle: "Roof Deck",
          allViewTitle: "All Photos",
          useDetailsView: false,
          selectCircleStrokeColor: "#000000",
        ),
      );
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      //String error = e.toString();
      print(e);
    }

    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      images = resultList;
    });
  }

  deleteImage(index) {
    images.removeAt(index);
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final topData = Provider.of<Selling>(context);
    final typeOfProperty = topData.menu;
    screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            // SizedBox(
            //   height: 1,
            // ),
            // Positioned(
            //   top: 0,
            //   left: 0,
            //   right: 0,
            //   child: Container(
            //     width: screenWidth,
            //     padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
            //     margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
            //     child: LinearPercentIndicator(
            //       width: screenWidth / 1.2,
            //       lineHeight: 8.0,
            //       percent: 0.50,
            //       progressColor: Colors.deepPurple[900],
            //     ),
            //   ),
            // ),
            Container(
              // width: screenWidth,
              // padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 5),
              // margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 5),
              child: CustomScrollView(
                slivers: [
                  SliverToBoxAdapter(
                    child: Container(
                      // padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      //   top: 5,
                      //   left: 15,
                      //   right: 15,
                      // ),
                      // margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      //   top: 5,
                      //   left: 15,
                      //   right: 15,
                      // ),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Center(
                            child: Text(
                              'Photos',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Divider(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            thickness: 2.00,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  // SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  //   child: Padding(
                  //     padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  //         left: 15.0, right: 15.0, bottom: 5.0),
                  //     child: Text(
                  //       'Homes are 30% more likely to sell with high quality photos.',
                  //       style: TextStyle(
                  //         color: Colors.grey,
                  //         fontSize: 18.00,
                  //       ),
                  //     ),
                  //   ),
                  // ),
                  // SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  //   child: Padding(
                  //     padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  //         left: 15.0, right: 15.0, bottom: 20.0),
                  //     child: Text(
                  //       'You can only upload 12 pictures, if you need to remove a picture just tap on it.',
                  //       style: TextStyle(
                  //         color: Colors.grey,
                  //         fontSize: 18.00,
                  //       ),
                  //     ),
                  //   ),
                  // ),
                  SliverPadding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 15,
                    ),
                    sliver: SliverGrid(
                      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                        (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return index == images.length
                              ? Center(
                                  child: DecoratedBox(
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.grey,
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                      border: Border.all(
                                          color: Colors.grey, width: 1.0),
                                    ),
                                    child: Container(
                                      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      height: 100,
                                      width: 100,
                                      child: IconButton(
                                        icon: Icon(
                                          Icons.add, //add_a_photo,
                                          size: 50.00,
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                        ),
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          if (images.length < 12) {
                                            loadAssets();
                                          } else {
                                            showDialog(
                                              context: context,
                                              builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
                                                title: Text(
                                                    'Max Number of Pictures'),
                                                content: Text(
                                                    'You reached the maximum number of pictures that can be uploaded (12 pictures)'),
                                                actions: [
                                                  TextButton(
                                                    child: Text('Okay'),
                                                    onPressed: () {
                                                      Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
                                                    },
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            );
                                          }
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )
                              : GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    deleteImage(index);
                                  },
                                  child: Container(
                                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(3),
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      border: Border.all(
                                          color: Colors.grey, width: 1.0),
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                        Radius.circular(5.0),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    child: ClipRRect(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
                                      child: AssetThumb(
                                        asset: images[index],
                                        width: 300,
                                        height: 300,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                        },
                        childCount: images.length + 1,
                      ),
                      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 3,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: 15,
                ),
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    TextButton(
                      child: Text(
                        'Previous',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        switch (typeOfProperty) {
                          case 0:
                            {
                              Navigator.pushNamed(
                                  context, PropertyBathrooms.routeName);
                            }
                            break;
                          case 1:
                            {
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                PageRouteBuilder(
                                    transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 0),
                                    pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) =>
                                        LandSizeFeatures()),
                              );
                            }
                            break;
                          case 2:
                            {
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                PageRouteBuilder(
                                    transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 0),
                                    pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) =>
                                        TownhousePropertyDetails()),
                              );
                            }
                            break;
                          case 3:
                            {
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                PageRouteBuilder(
                                    transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 0),
                                    pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) =>
                                        CondoPropertyDetails()),
                              );
                            }
                            break;
                          case 4:
                            {
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                PageRouteBuilder(
                                    transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 0),
                                    pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) =>
                                        HomePropertyDetails()),
                              );
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                        // Navigator.pushNamed(
                        //     context, PropertyBathrooms.routeName);
                      },
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      child: Text(
                        'Next',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Provider.of<Selling>(context, listen: false)
                            .getImages(images);
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          PageRouteBuilder(
                              transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 0),
                              pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => PricingProperty()),
                        );
                        //Navigator.pushNamed(context, PropertySize.routeName);
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavBar(2),
    );
  }
}
```

Once we move to a different screen I save that list to a Provider to have it available in any place:

```
//***Property Images***/

  List<Asset> _images = <Asset>[];

  //Images Getter

  List<Asset> get images {
    return _images;
  }

  //Filling the Data Function

  void getImages(List<Asset> images) {
    _images = images;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  //*** END OF IMAGES ***//
```

The code above is how I fill the images in the Images provider.

Now all of these works, however the questions is that now I wish to upload all the images in that list to Firebase Storage and get back a List of Strings with the Picture Viewing URL (DownloadURL).

I'm able to do this by doing it in a 1 by 1 case and sending a File not a List of Assets like this code:

```
final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
                .ref()
                .child('user_images')
                .child(authResult.user.uid + '.jpg');

            await ref.putFile(image);

            final url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
```

But is there a way to do this all at once instead of 1 by 1 and retrieve the List of Strings of the download URL?

My End Goal is to be able to have those images store in Firebase Storage and save to Firestore the Array of the urls for those images.

In my resume, my problem is that I'm not uploading a File or a List of Files, instead, I'm uploading a List of Assets, and that it is a List and not a single one.

Thank you and Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody comes here for an Answer I found it:

1. First I added the List < File > to my Multi Image Picker and added this code (resultList is the Asset Array).

I add the package *flutter_absolute_path: ^1.0.6* and with that got the following code:

```
resultList.forEach((imageAsset) async {
      final filePath =
          await FlutterAbsolutePath.getAbsolutePath(imageAsset.identifier);

      File tempFile = File(filePath);

      if (tempFile.existsSync()) {
        fileImageArray.add(tempFile);
      }
    });
```

With that I save to my Provider the File Array. Then I created a Function to do the Upload to Firebase Storage:

```
Future<void> uploadImages(String id) async {
    int i = 0;
    for (File imageFile in imageFiles) {
      try {
        var ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
            .ref()
            .child('ListingImages')
            .child(id)
            .child(i.toString() + '.jpg');

        await ref.putFile(imageFile);

        var url = await ref.getDownloadURL();

        _imagesUrl.add(url);

        i++;
      } catch (err) {
        print(err);
      }
    }
    notifyListeners();
    print(_imagesUrl);
  }
```

Allowing me to loop over each file uploaded and saved the Download URL in a String Array.

Hope this helps you, Guys.